# Can´t open Documents by Webportal from a mapped NetworShare by WebDAV

Tags: c#, webdav, connectivity, network-share, dmz

I have the following problem:

I mapped a Network-Share from outside a DMZ to a Server inside the DMZ.

UNC-Path (for Example):

`\\X3F12D1001D123.Server@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Program\03_Data\01_LS\`

Here I´m able to open all the different kind of documents.

On the same Server I have a Webportal, which is contactable from the Internet.
When a User is connected with the Webportal, and is trying to open a Document, he get the response that the File doesn´t exists, but it does.

The Code I use therefor usually works, so I think it should be a problem with some safety rules.

Maybe someone had such a problem to and can give some useful Input.

Comment: Make sure that the web portal is running under permissions that allow it to see the files

Comment: As I see it should be everything alright